# How to explain the behavior of this insert statement involving current_date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I am trying a very simple test query on a forked MPP version of postgreSQL 8.2 and I am trying to figure out if this is expected behavior.

When I do an insert statement for a single row using current_date I get the expected output for the current date:

```
create table test( t_date timestamp without time zone);

insert into test(  t_date)
VALUES
(
current_date::date
),


 db=> select * from test ;
           t_date        
    ---------------------
     2013-08-19 00:00:00
    (1 row)
```

But when I add more than one row to the insert statement I get an unexpected result - is this part of the standard?

```
insert into test(  t_date)
VALUES
(
current_date::date
),
(
current_date::date
);

   db=>  select * from test ;
           t_date        
    ---------------------
     1999-12-31 00:00:00
     1999-12-31 00:00:00
    (2 rows)
```

> My question is :  Why does the first insert statement output the correct date when I use current_date::date and the second insert outputs two incorrect dates when I use the same current_date::date cast?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.2.(what)? On what platform? You're using a pretty ancient and unsupported version. The results I get on 9.2.4 are exactly what you would expect.

Comment: I am working on an MPP database called Greenplum that is forked  off Postgresql so I cant control the fact that it is old.  I am trying to determine if this is a bug in the platform we are on or genuine expected output.

Comment: Well, it would help if you'd mentioned that - "I'm using Greenplum 4.2, which is based on PostgreSQL 8.2". I've updated the tags.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on our installation of Greenplum 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That result is incorrect, unexpected, and bizarre.

PostgreSQL 9.2.4 produces the correct result.

```
regress=> select * from test;
       t_date        
---------------------
 2013-08-20 00:00:00
 2013-08-20 00:00:00
(2 rows)
```

[as does 8.3, the oldest version I can be bothered testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/99a5a/1).

Whatever patched / hacked up version of PostgreSQL you're using has introduced a bug.

Comment: thanks that is very helpful I guess the only thing to do is check it on 8.2 and then file a JIRA if all else fails...

Comment: @user7980 I'd just file a bug with greenplum directly. The result of that query is clearly and obviously incorrect irrespective of how 8.2 behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's a feature of Postgresql to allow "bulk" loading using the VALUES clause.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-insert.html

See the section under:

> To insert multiple rows using the multirow VALUES syntax:

Comment: Thanks but I still expect that output for the second insert statement to be 2013-08-19 00:00:00 like in the first insert.   The document you linked to does not resolve my question.

Comment: Oh, my answer was entirely useless, sorry. I somehow skipped over the relevant part of your question entirely.